# I am facing this error Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress

Tags: php, mysql

my website is fine till yeaterday. Today when i open my website url saw this error. Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress. Even i am unable to access admin panel. I have tried setting up older version of php. Tried updating wordpress. But no use.
Please guide me what will be the issue and solution for the same.
Thank you,
Varsharani Agare

Comment: I suggest contacting your host for assistance.

Comment: I am in touch with them.. But I need to know the issue. Can you please tell me possibility where is the problem?

Comment: The problem is described in the error message: "Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress." Only your host can tell which extension is missing and resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem just now, when I upgraded to PHP 7.4 & removed the older version.

If you are on Nginx server, you need to update the configuration file

```
location ~* \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass  unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
```